# Nodejs Soap Client - ETIMEDOUT to JAX-WS Soap webservice

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, jax-ws, node-soap

I am trying to create a Soap Client in my local NodeJs application to call our Legacy system (Java) which have JAX-WS webservices (SOAP) exposed. This webservice is deployed on Tomcat EC2 instance. The ELB only accepts traffic on port 443 and directs the call to EC2-instance listening on port:80.

If I expose a RestAPI end-point on the legacy web-application and use the 'request' module the nodejs code is able to call the Rest-Endpoint.

If its a soap webservice then I get the below error. It would be really great if you guys could guide me in the right direction.

I always get the below error:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xx.xx.xxx.xxx:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx',
  port: 80 }
```

Below is my soap-client code: using the node-module: https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap

```
var soap = require('soap');
var path = require("path");
            var options = {
                ignoredNamespaces: {
                    namespaces: ['targetNSAlias']
                },
                timeout: 120000,
                port:443
            };

           soap.createClient("https://hostname/service?WSDL", options,function(err, client) {

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the address may not be correct, I recommend that you verify the connection information or try with SoapUI to validate that everything works correctly.

Comment: You can use nmap to check for open ports or telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port_number to check if the server is accepting connections on the port_number